# Toggle Button in Visual Studio (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to make a toggle button for pausing and starting something. This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub playpause_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles playpause.Click
    Dim ispaused As Boolean = True
    If ispaused = True Then
        playpause.Text = "Pause"
        ispaused = False
    Else
        playpause.Text = "Play"
        ispaused = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The text changes to Pause, but it doesn't change back to Play. Can someone help me and get this to work?

Comment: Look at this line: `Dim ispaused As Boolean = True` (also look where it is declared at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No boolean needed, just check the text:

```
Private Sub playpause_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles playpause.Click
 If playpause.Text = "Pause"
   playpause.Text = "Play"
    'do stuff for pause
 Else 'it was "Play"
   playpause.Text = "Pause"
    'do stuff for play
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 'do stuff for pause and 'do stuff for play I would make them other Sub methods in order to have separation of concerns.

Comment: @Moojjoo, that is still an option with this format, but is not a requirement

Comment: Just trying to decouple code...  It is the age old debate.  Over normalize.  @OneFineDay

Comment: What if the code is one line, why do you need a separate sub?